# how to get the trigger information in Jenkins programmatically

Tags: jenkins, triggers

I need to add the next build time scheduled in a build email notification after a build in Jenkins.

The trigger can be "`Build periodically`" or "`Poll SCM`", or anything with schedule time.

I know the trigger info is in the config.xml file e.g.

```
<triggers>
    <hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
      <spec>8 */2 * * 1-5</spec>
      <ignorePostCommitHooks>false</ignorePostCommitHooks>
    </hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
  </triggers>
```

and I also know how to get the trigger type and spec with custom scripting from the config.xml file, and calculate the next build time.

I wonder if Jenkins has the API to expose this information out-of-the-box. I have done the search, but not found anything.

Answer (score 4):

I realise you probably no longer need help with this, but I just had to solve the same problem, so here is a script you can use in the Jenkins console to output all trigger configurations:

```
#!groovy

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems().each { it ->
  if (!(it instanceof jenkins.triggers.SCMTriggerItem)) {
    return
  }

  def itTrigger = (jenkins.triggers.SCMTriggerItem)it
  def triggers = itTrigger.getSCMTrigger()

  println("Job ${it.name}:")

  triggers.each { t->
    println("\t${t.getSpec()}")
    println("\t${t.isIgnorePostCommitHooks()}")
  }
}
```

This will output all your jobs that use SCM configuration, along with their specification (cron-like expression regarding when to run) and whether post-commit hooks are set to be ignored.

You can modify this script to get the data as JSON like this:

```
#!groovy
import groovy.json.*

def result = [:]

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems().each { it ->
  if (!(it instanceof jenkins.triggers.SCMTriggerItem)) {
    return
  }

  def itTrigger = (jenkins.triggers.SCMTriggerItem)it
  def triggers = itTrigger.getSCMTrigger()

  triggers.each { t->
    def builder = new JsonBuilder()
    result[it.name] = builder {
      spec "${t.getSpec()}"
      ignorePostCommitHooks "${t.isIgnorePostCommitHooks()}"
    }
  }
}

return new JsonBuilder(result).toPrettyString()
```

And then you can use the [Jenkins Script Console web API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) to get this from an HTTP client.

For example, in curl, you can do this by saving your script as a text file and then running:

```
curl --data-urlencode "script=$(<./script.groovy)" <YOUR SERVER>/scriptText
```

If Jenkins is using basic authentication, you can supply that with the -u `<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>` argument.

Ultimately, the request will result in something like this:

```
{
    "Build Project 1": {
        "spec": "H/30 * * * *",
        "ignorePostCommitHooks": "false"
    },
    "Test Something": {
        "spec": "@hourly",
        "ignorePostCommitHooks": "false"
    },
    "Deploy ABC": {
        "spec": "H/20 * * * *",
        "ignorePostCommitHooks": "false"
    }
}
```

You should be able to tailor these examples to fit your specific use case. It seems you won't need to access this remotely but just from a job, but I also included the remoting part as it might come in handy for someone else.

Comment: I had similar idea while ago, but I gave up because I can't run system groovy scripts from a slave machine, and the build environment is under tight control.

Comment: At my company, I built an extra layer between the end user and the script console API. There is a system that stores such Groovy scripts, they are administrator-approved, and there is a web API that allows users to execute them through that system (the content of the script is abstracted away). In Jenkins pipelines, users can trigger that intermediate API via an HTTP request, for example using this: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin. There is certainly an overhead in maintaining such a tool, but it's so far worth it, as implementing it has been a one-time effort.